How to improve performance and make UI thread free in knockout.js for below code?
We have this below code which has 2 responsibilities to do:

If we have checked a node then all it's children nodes should be selected.
If a child node is deselected then all its parents node should be deselected.

PS: We have children length upto 10 thousand data and to render it it gives "UI unresponsivness" errors multiple times. Even it's started happening for 1000 children length. :(
             node.checked = ko.computed(
                    {
                        read: function ()
                        {
                            var checked = true;
                            var children = node.children();

                            for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
                            {
                                if (!children[i].checked())
                                {
                                    checked = false;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            return checked;
                        },
                        write: function (newValue)
                        {
                            var children = node.children();

                            for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
                            {
                                children[i].checked(newValue)
                            }
                        },
                    })


If all parent/child nodes must have the same value for "selected", then why have a computed at all?  Could each parent node have one value for "selected" and all children reference parent.selected?
